# How to get file from s3 bucket using raspberry pi

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to get a file from s3 bucket  using raspberrypi, i have full access for S3,still there is an error saying s3: error 403: forbidden, on googling about it,it says my device doesn't have the required permissions but i am using the ask cli with my access key and secret key and as stated earlier i have full access for s3, still this error can anyone please help?
Have tried :
sudo s3cmd get s3://bucket name/filename

Comment: What's in your bucket policy?

Comment: thank you for the reply, it got sorted, you are right, i was missing some permissions as well as some other parameters were missing.